# An explicit formula of $\|\,f\,\|_0$ where $f \in L^p(S, \Sigma, \mu)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

The following question is from *Problem VII 11.32* in *Linear Operators* edited by **Nelson Dunford** and **Jacob T. Schwartz**.

Assume $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a probability space and $f \in L^p(S, \Sigma, \mu)$(where $p > 0$ but not necessarily $\geq 1$). Using Hölder's inequality we can show that $\|\,f\,\|_p$ is a monotone function of $p$ for any $p > 0$. Now show that as $p \downarrow 0, \|\,f\,\|_p \downarrow \exp[\int_S \log\vert\,f(s)\,\vert\mu(ds)]$, which will be called $\|\,f\,\|_0$.
Furthermore, this result can also apply to any element $g \in L^p(X, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{v})$ where $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{v})$ is a positive measure space, $p > 0$ and the support of $g$ has finite measure.

If we let $f \in L^p(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a simple function, it suffices to consider the sequence $\{\|\,f\,\|_{\frac{1}{n}}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Without losing generality, we can assme $f = \sum_{i \leq k}r_i\chi_{A_i}$ where all $r_i$ are real numbers. Then we may need to directly show $$\|\,f\,\|_{\frac{1}{n}} = \exp[n \log(\sum_{i \leq k}r_i^{\frac{1}{n}}\mu(A_i))] \rightarrow \exp[\sum_{i \leq k}(\log r_i)\mu(A_i)] = \prod_{i \leq k}r_i\exp(\mu(A_i))$$ which is not obvious to me ... Any hints about this convergence or new ideas to attack on this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: The book has been used for a long time  by hundreds of Mathematicians. I seriously doubt if your claim that the book has lots of miatakes is true.

Comment: I might be wrong when I say "I found mistakes" .... I will just delete that line then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two facts to prove the convergence:

1. $n(t^{1/n}-1) \to \ln t$ for all $t >0$.  To see this note that $t^{1/n}-1=e^{1/n \ln t}-1\sim \frac {\ln t} n $
2. $n \ln (\sum r_i^{1/n} \mu(A_i))\sim n  (\sum r_i^{1/n} \mu(A_i)-1)=
   n (\sum (r_i^{1/n}-1) \mu(A_i))$ since $\sum \mu(A_i)=1$. [I ahve used the fact that $\ln x \sim x-1$ as $x \to 1$.

Comment: Very nice techniques! You just hinted me a very good way of proving convergence using calculus ideas.